# Implementing monadic bind for Nullable<> *and* reference types

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullable, monads

I have this function:

```
public static U? IfNotNull<T, U>(this T? self, Func<T, U?> func)
    where T : struct
    where U : struct
{
    return (self.HasValue) ? func(self.Value) : null;
}
```

Example:

```
int? maybe = 42;
maybe.IfNotNull(n=>2*n); // 84

maybe = null;
maybe.IfNotNull(n=>2*n); // null
```

I want it to work on implicitly-nullable reference types as well as explicit `Nullable<>` types. This implementation would work:

```
public static U IfNotNull<T, U>(this T? self, Func<T, U> func)
    where T : struct
    where U : class
{
    return (self.HasValue) ? func(self.Value) : null;
}
```

But of course overload resolution does not look at type constraints, so you can't have both at once. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Can't you just remove the where clause?

Comment: You could simple rename the second function. If the problem are the different return types...

Comment: No: the `U` in the first function must be declared `struct` to be `Nullable`'d, and the `U` in the second function must be declared `class` so that the `null` can be returned as a `U`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But of course overload resolution does not look at type constraints

Well it does... but not the type constraints of the method itself. It looks at type constraints on the *parameter* types.

In C# 4 (which has optional parameters) you *can* do this... but I'd *really* suggest you don't:

```
public class MustBeStruct<T> where T : struct {}
public class MustBeClass<T> where T : class {}

public static U? IfNotNull<T, U>(this T? self, Func<T, U?> func,
                       MustBeStruct<U> ignored = default(MustBeStruct<U>))
    where T : struct
    where U : struct
{
    return (self.HasValue) ? func(self.Value) : null;
}

public static U IfNotNull<T, U>(this T? self, Func<T, U> func,
                                MustBeClass<U> ignored = null)
    where T : struct
    where U : class
{
    return (self.HasValue) ? func(self.Value) : null;
}
```

See [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround.aspx) for more details of this horrible, horrible hack.

Personally I'd probably just name the two methods differently so that overload resolution didn't need to work so hard - and neither did the readers of your code.

Comment: This is the best worst answer I have seen in a while. I am impressed and appalled.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with this:

```
public static U IfNotNull<T, U>(this T self, Func<T, U> func)
    where U : class
{
    return (self != null)
        ? func(self)
        : (U)null;
}

public static U? IfNotNull<T, U>(this T self, Func<T, U?> func)
    where U : struct
{
    return (self != null)
        ? (U?)func(self)
        : null;
}
```

The overload resolver seems to be happy with this. It's a tiny bit of extra work for `Nullable<>` types:

```
object o = null;
o.IfNotNull(x => x.ToString());
o.IfNotNull(x => x.GetHashCode() as int?);

int? i = null;
i.IfNotNull(x => Math.Abs(x.Value).ToString());
i.IfNotNull(x => Math.Abs(x.Value) as int?);
```